# Scroll children content inside <frame> on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, frame

What's the best way to scroll content from inside the loaded page inside that . I know the Apple developer documentation tells us to stay away from `<framesets>` and `<frames>` but I unfortunately we can't due to client restrictions.

The HTML is set up as such:

```
<frameset rows="0,0,0,*,0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0">
<frame id="frm1" name="frm1" src="some-aspx-page" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" noresize="">
<frame id="frm2" name="frm2" src="result.htm" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" noresize="">
<frame id="frm3" name="frm3" src="result.htm" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" noresize="">
<frame id="lesson" name="lesson" src="index.html">
<frame id="frm4" src="some-aspx-page" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" noresize="">
```

I know that iOS frames and iframes expand up to the width and height of the content. With an iframe loading the content (as a test) , I was able to do the following for iOS:

```
  var parentBody = window.parent.document.body; 
  var parentHTML = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('html');

  $('.button').on('click', function(e)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(parentBody, parentHTML).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400);
  }
```

For some reason, I can't do the same with `<frameset>` and `<frame>`. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**Update:** The content and the page parent page containing the `<frame>` are on the same domain.

Comment: Do you need to pull content from several different domains into one webpage? Otherwise, I can't think of anything you could do with frames that couldn't be done better with AJAX and scrollable DIVs.

Comment: @Blazemonger Well the client system is a LMS, and the LMS, they are utilizing uses the extra frames to load in SCORM APIs for the course content to call, etc... I have no control over how the system is set up, sadly.